# Excel 2011 - Pulling data from multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a series of project models (all different workbooks) which contains deals that we have sold. The model itself are in two half's, top is costs and bottom is revenue. Along the rows are the names of the deals and the columns are in monthly dates, this gives us our revenue per month. I am trying to consolidate only the revenue data from these multiple workbooks into one file for the account, automating this process instead of just going into every workbook and or copy and pasting data will save me a lot of time.

How can I do this? in VBA or using Vlookup somehow?

Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: This forum is for help with code you've already written. If you want more help you need to show what you've tried and the specific errors you are getting. Try recording a macro to get you started. You should start a new question for specific problems you can't resolve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is great for this: If you have the files in a folder you can loop through the files. Google FileSystemObject for more information.

```
'Need Tools > Reference choose Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
```

Create a loop to open the file, locate the data and copy to your consolidated workbook.